# Android EditText validation with possibility to continue

Tags: android, validation, android-alertdialog

I have a succession of verifications applying to user input before submitting the data. Each verification, if failed, will popup a dialog to the user.

```
if (check_1() == false) {
    popup(MSG_1);
    return false;
}
if (check_2() == false) {
    popup(MSG_2);
    return false;
}
...
```

My issue is that I want one of the verification to overridable by the user, like the `check_2` below :

```
if (check_1() == false) {
    popup(MSG_1);
    return false;
}
if (check_2() == false) {
    boolean res = popup_with_override(MSG_2);   // confirmation dialog
    if (res == false)
       return false;
    // otherwise continue with the validation tests
}
if (check_3() == false) {
    popup(MSG_3);
    return false;
}
...
```

I tried to use a confirmation dialog like the class below, but it does not fit well with the idea of a list of tests that get verified one after the other.

```
public abstract static class DialogCallback implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener, Runnable {
    public DialogCallback(Context c, String q) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);
        builder.setMessage(q)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", this)
                .setNegativeButton("No", this);
        builder.create().show();
    }

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE) {
            mWhich = DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE;
            run();
        } else {
            mWhich = DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE;
            run();
        }
    }

    //
    public int mWhich;
}
```

Since the alert dialog is not blocking in Android, I think the approach has to be rewritten : like separating the overridable validations from the other verifications ?

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have used the following approach to address my need (looping over multiple overridable verification), if it can help others :

1) My check function does not return boolean anymore. Instead in case of error, we just collect the error in a `List<ValidationError>`, `ValidationError` being a class containing the error message, the concerned `EditText` (or null if global error), and the boolean `overridable` (or not). Thus the verification code becomes :

```
if (check_1() == false) {
    // non-edittext specific error
    ValidationErrors.add(new ValidationError(MSG_1, null, false)); 
}
if (check_2() == false) {
    // overridable error = warning
    ValidationErrors.add(new ValidationError(MSG_2, editText2, true)); 
}
if (check_3() == false) {
    // edittext specific error
    ValidationErrors.add(new ValidationError(MSG_3, editText3, false)); 
}
```

2) Then a validation method allows to continue to the real work or warn/stop the user :

```
void Validate() {

    ArrayList<String> warnings = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (ValidationError ve : ValidationErrors) {
        // global err : display & return
        if (ve.editText == null && !ve.overridable) {
            popup(ve.message);
            return;
        }
        // local err : mark the edittext & return
        if (ve.editText != null && !ve.overridable) {
            ve.editText.setError(ve.message);
            return;
        }
        // global warning : collect the message
        if (ve.editText == null && ve.overridable) {
            warnings.add(ve.message);
        }
        // local warning : mark the edittext & collect the message
        if (ve.editText != null && ve.overridable) {
            ve.editText.setError(ve.message);
            warnings.add(ve.message);
        }
    }

    // Confirm (or not) the warnings
    ConfirmWarnings(warnings);
}
```

3) Finally the `ConfirmWarnings` method is recursive so it can loop over all warnings if any :

```
void ConfirmWarnings(ArrayList<String> warns) {
    if (warns.size() > 0) {
        new DialogCallback(this, warns.get(0) + ", continue ?", tags) {
            @override
            public void run() {
                if (this.mWhich == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE) {
                    warns.remove(0); // consume the warnings as they are accepted
                    ConfirmWarnings(warns);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else 
        RealWork();
}
```